# Opening a url on launch

Tags: cocoa, notifications, launch

What method must I implement in my cocoa application’s delegate so that on launch, it’ll open a url? (http/https, in this case) I’ve already implemented the url schemes, I just need to know how I can get my application to open on a url notification.

**Update:** I’m sorry, I wasn’t very clear. My application IS a browser that support https/http urls, but can only open them when it’s already running. What can I do to implement support for open urls in my app on launch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already had implemented the getURL event, so that alone isn’t enough to get the application to open a url on launch. The trick is that the AppleEvent must be installed in applicationWillFinishLaunching: not applicationDidFinishLaunching:. Otherwise, the event isn’t sent at all because the app hasn’t registered it in time.

Answer (score 8):

When an application finishes launching on OS X, `NSApp` (the global `NSApplication` instance for the program) sends its delegate the [`applicationDidFinishLaunching:`](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSApplicationDelegate/applicationDidFinishLaunching:) message (via the notification system). You can implement that method in your delegate to handle the notification and open a browser window in response, using [`NSWorkspace`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/openURL:). Something like the following would work:

```
// Your NSApp delegate
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/"]];
}
```

Comment: I know this bit already, but thanks! What I meant is what method can I implement that will allow my application to open urls itself? My app can already handle opening urls when its running, but is only launched when a url is clicked elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a delegate method. You need to implement an Apple Event handler for the getURL event.

As luck would have it, this is exactly the case Apple uses [to demonstrate implementing an Apple Event handler](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_handle_AEs/SAppsHandleAEs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001239-BBCIDFHG).

Answer (score 0):

To implement a protocol handler that you can select (in Safari preferences, for example) as the "default browser" and which will launch in response to HTTP / HTTPS, you need to do a few things.

1. Add .scriptSuite and .scriptTerminology files to your project resources. These will tell Mac OS X that you'll be handling the GetURL command.
2. Add a CFBundleURLTypes key to your Info.plist file listing the "URL Schemes" that your app will handle.
3. Also in Info.plist, add the NSAppleScriptEnabled key with the value YES.
4. Add a new class to your application as a subclass of NSScriptCommand and implement the -(id)performDefaultImplementation selector. From within this function you will find the clicked URL in [self directParameter]. Pass this on to your app's URL handler!

For the full details check out the article:
http://www.xmldatabases.org/WK/blog/1154_Handling_URL_schemes_in_Cocoa.item